# Best Project Management certification for international career

Tags: career, certification

I am newbie to project management. I am looking for a certification to pursue an international project management career in Europe. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PMI.org certs are the most portable, in my experience. The organization has a lot of history and has most of their materials available in multiple languages. The exact certification to pursue would depend on your background, though. https://www.pmi.org/certifications/types has the details.

Answer (score 1):

In my view [Project Management Professional, PMP](https://www.pmi.org/certifications/types/project-management-pmp)  is the one you should go for

Comment: Opinion-only answers are discouraged. Please include either relevant personal experience or empirical studies.